# SSE2 instructions don't seem to have any effect in WinCE6

Tags: x86, windows-ce, sse

I have been trying to speed up the execution of a very time-consuming calculation in our C++ application (in my test case it runs for about 10 to 15 minutes before the result is complete). This application runs on both Win32 and WindowsCE 6 (on a target with an Atom-processor).

In an attempt to optimize the generated code, I enabled SSE2 instructions in VC++2008 (compiler option '/arch:SSE2').

I checked some of the generated .cod files and verified that the code for both targets is the same, different than before the change, and does indeed contains SSE instructions.

The weird thing is, the speed *does* increase about 25% when running on Windows 7 (both on my desktop PC and on the Atom board), but there is absolutely *no noticeable difference* when running it on Windows CE (the same Atom board). All tests done with release build.

I can't figure out what the problem might be. Does anyone have any clues or a similar experience? Is CE6 doing something (or not doing something?) to prevent the code from executing at the optimal speed?